# Antd Slider not shown

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use `antd` `Slider` component in form.
So I put it the way shown in this sandbox

[image: Edit antd-slider]

BUT

in sandbox - it works fine, and in my project - it's not visible.

[image]

Applying `style={{display: ...}}` or `style={{height: ...}}` didn't help.

Devtools show that elements with classnames `ant-slider-rail`, `ant-slider-track` have `height:0`

I'm out of ideas why that could happen?

Comment: anything in the console ?

Comment: @sazzad No, console is clear, no warnings or errors

Comment: Can you show your code what have you done?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma It is the same as in sandbox. It's a part of bigger form but the structure and important parts are the same

Comment: What I understand there is higher chances Your css in not importing correctly.Try checking that out

Comment: @ShubhamVerma You were right! 
It's a part of big SPA and `antd` styles were imported per-component.
So I had to add `@import "~antd/lib/slider/style/index";`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. here is the solution
you should import the css file

```
import { Slider } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what worked for me.
See my comment above.
I'm importing styles for each component separately to reduce bundle size, that's why path for import is a bit different.